# `impl<T: MyTrait> From<T> for A` conflicts with default implmentation

Tags: rust

### Problem

I'm trying to implement the `From` trait on `A` for all types that have another trait `MyTrait`. However in the case that `A` also implements `MyTrait`, I'm getting an error.

**How can I implement the `From` trait on `A` for all types that are not `A`?**

### Example

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ff54f9c1e0f215a1d608f2281442c5d1)

```rust
struct A {}

trait MyTrait {}

impl MyTrait for A {}

impl<T: MyTrait> From<T> for A {
    fn from(_value: T) -> Self {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `From<A>` for type `A`
 --> src/lib.rs:7:1
  |
7 | impl<T: MyTrait> From<T> for A {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
          - impl<T> From<T> for T;

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0119`.
error: could not compile `playground` (lib) due to previous error
```

Comment: You can't, because it conflicts with the blanket implementation `impl<T> From<T> for T` in the standard library. This may be possible when/if specialization lands, but it's not possible today.